# How to detect Windows 8 app going to background

Tags: c#, events, windows-8

My question is quite simple, is there any event or a way to detect when my application is no longer in the foreground - when user has swathed to other app?

The thing i want to do, i want to pause some functions and activities when the user doesn't use the app.

The functions onActivating and onSuspending don't do...

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: onSuspending doesn't do what? Be much clearer about what you need and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visibility changed event should be enough for your needs:

```
Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += (s, e) => 
{
    if (!e.Visible)
    {
        // Application went to background
    }
    else 
    {
        // Application is FullScreen again
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trice. Will mark it in 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The [OS handles suspension and resumption for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx), so you shouldn't need to pause those activities:

> When the user moves an app to the background, the OS waits a few seconds to see whether the user immediately switches back to the app. If the user does not switch back, the OS suspends the app.
>
> If an app has registered an event handler for the **Suspending | suspending** event, this event handler is called right before the app is suspended. You can use the event handler to save relevant app and user data to persistent storage. We recommended that you use the application data APIs for this purpose because they are guaranteed to complete before the app enters the **Suspended** state.

Comment: not correct. When i switch the app, all timers keep on running

Comment: What makes you think the timers carry on, whilst your app is suspended? how are you observing the behaviour?

Comment: If i add lets say a label, and change its text on timer tick label.text = i++; then i can see how it changes in app list (that is shown on my question image). And also when i open the app i can see that label.text is much bigger then it was when it went to background